# Почему в Atom не разворачивается выражение Emmet в html по нажатию на Tab?

Tags: atom, emmet

При нажатии <kbd>Tab</kbd> плагин не разворачивает сокращенное написание.
Как пофиксить данную проблему?

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Comment: это значит что при нажатии tab плагин не разворачивает сокращенное написание. Те кто пользуются данным инструментом понимают о чем речь

Comment: Нет, не понимают. Потому что "не работает" может проявляться в совершенно разных вариациях.

Comment: Например в каких?

Comment: Например, недавно была проблема, что выражения разворачивались без форматирования (отступов) в одну строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем от простого к сложному.

Во-первых, установите плагин [Emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom).

Во-вторых, проверьте, где вы пытаетесь развернуть аббревиатуру.

По умолчанию раскрытие работает в HTML, CSS, Sass/SCSS и LESS файлах.
Это сделано из-за того, что обработчик <kbd>Tab</kbd> перезаписывает стандартные сниппеты.
Чтобы раскрывать аббревиатуры в других файлах, вам нужно:

- Выбрать меню `File` → `Open Your Keymap`
- Добавить туда следующий код

  ```
  'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="YOUR GRAMMAR HERE"]:not([mini])':
    'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
  ```

Замените `YOUR GRAMMAR HERE` настоящим значением. Самый простой способ узнать корректное значение, это открыть DevTools (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) и найти элемент `<atom-text-editor>`. В нем будет атрибут `data-grammar` с нужным вам значением. Например, для HTML это будет `text html basic`.

Вы можете добавить столько секций, сколько вам нужно, для разных типов файлов. Однако учтите, что стандартные сниппеты перестанут работать.

Comment: Для того чтобы работал в `.php` `YOUR GRAMMAR HERE` будит равно `ext html php`

Answer (score 0):

Как я обнаружил шорткаты переделали, то есть вместо tab надо жать ctrl+e

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]